# Double base path when using push with basename

Tags: react-router

I've come across an issue which I've been trying to figure whether I'm just doing something wrong or whether it's an actual bug. After a lot of searching, I still can't figure out if I'm doing something wrong or if I've found an actual problem.

Part of the reason as to why I'm so confused is also because I found the intersection between react-router and history a bit confusing. It took me a while to figure out exactly how to use history's enhancer functions with react-router and I still think the issue might lay there.

I have a test case here:

- https://github.com/trodrigues/react-router-basename-test
- http://trodrigues.github.io/react-router-basename-test/

And the problem is:

- Clicking the button issues a this.context.router.push call to navigate to `/content/path`
- I'd expect it to navigate to http://trodrigues.github.io/react-router-basename-test/content/path
- Instead it navigates to http://trodrigues.github.io/react-router-basename-test/react-router-basename-test/content/path

Some additional detail:

- If I use the `<base>` tag instead of the `useBasename` enhancer this works fine. However, given that I have a slightly different setup for dev and production, using an environment variable to define the basepath would be more helpful, rather than manipulating the `<base>` tag at build time.
- The sample app I uploaded is a minimal subset of the app I'm working on. I removed everything else that didn't matter.
- The issue **does not occur** when running this locally with a basepath set to an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

After some further investigation I figured out react-router [already uses](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/d6efd92287c10e9569d0522ab32fb2b333ea26e9/modules/useRouterHistory.js) the `useBasename` enhancer when using `useRouterHistory`, which is the cause of the problem as the enhancer gets executed twice.

Comment: Is there a way to override the useBasename? The docs here say its possible - https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#customize-your-history-further

Comment: @trodrigues Do you have a solution for this?